# How to display a long Select statement to display on one line, preferably in SQL Server Management Studio, or other editor?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I would like to display a long SELECT statement on one line, preferably in SQL Server Management Studio's editor, but another editor will do if not possible. I have the feeling it is one of those easy things, and I am missing the trick.

So:

```
SELECT 
col1,
col2,
col3
FROM Table1
```

should be:

```
SELECT col1, col2, col3 FROM Table1
```

Thanks

Comment: can you elaborate the question???

Comment: Your question is really not clear. Voting to close as such.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. In SSMS when you right click on a table, and select "Select Top 100 rows" it creates the SQL, which is great, but it puts the SQL on multiple lines ie it wraps it as per my example above. For code reasons, I would like it to be on one line so I can copy it, as one line, as my "should be" example.

Comment: By the sounds of things you're going to add SQL statements into your code, which will possibly open you up to SQL Injection attacks. You might be better off creating a stored procedure that takes parameters and executes the SQL and returns the results. Your code then simply has to call the stored procedure.

Comment: @Tanner, thanks for this. Yes O know about SQL Injection attacks. This code is for copying records, so no data taken from UI. I did start with a SP, but the logic got so complicated, so have developed V1 via C#, LINQ and EF. I may convert it back to a SP later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use find and replace with the new line character `\n`:

[image]

You can quickly access find and replace by hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd>.  Make sure you have "Use: Regular Expressions" selected.